# ¿Cómo convertir valores del campo de una tabla a columnas ? usando mysql

Tags: mysql

Saludos.

Me vendría bien un poco de ayuda para poder resolver el siguiente problema.

¿Cómo puedo convertir los valores del campo de una tabla en columnas? 
De que forma sería el query en mysql para poder hacerlo posible.

Tengo la siguiente tabla :

*usuario* | *empresa* | *hora* | *accion* 
juan - BCP - 09:10 - entrada 
juan - BCP - 10:11 - salida 
juan - BCP - 11:00 - entrada 
juan - BCP - 13:08 - salida

Y busco el query que pueda mostrar la información de la siguiete forma :

*usuario* | *empresa* | *entrada* | *salida* 
juan - BCP - 09:10 - 10:11 
juan - BCP - 11:00 - 13:08

¿Es posible llegar a este resultado en mysql?
Agradecería la ayuda para resolver este problema.

Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Mira a ver si te da el resultado que necesitas.

```
SELECT tabla1.usuario,tabla1.empresa,tabla1.hora as entrada, tabla2.hora as salida 
FROM(SELECT usuario,empresa,hora FROM tabla WHERE accion='entrada' GROUP BY usuario,empresa) as tabla1
      LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT usuario,empresa,hora FROM tabla WHERE accion='salida' GROUP BY usuario,empresa) as tabla2
ON tabla1.usuario=tabla2.usuario AND tabla1.empresa=tabla2.empresa
```

Comment: Hola Hictus.

Probé el query que publicaste pero no me dió el resultado esperado.
Con tu query , de los 4 registros de la tabla ejemplo que publiqué, solo me mostró los 2 primeros en una sola linea (justo lo que busco) pero los otros 2 registros ya no se lista.

Partiendo de tu query seguiré intentando.
Gracias.

Comment: Buenas @Ladislao, prueba a eliminar los GROUP BY de las querys

Comment: Saludos Hictus. Lo de quitar los GROUP BY fue lo primero que se me ocurrió pero igual no me dio el resultado deseado.